# How do you use Tensorboard to visualise my Chatbot? What can I learn from it?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, tensorflow

I am currently learning DeepLearning and wanted to ask a few questions in relation to my current project https://github.com/deepcollege/deeplearning/blob/master/030-chatbot/chatbot_simple.py

First of all, how do you generate an useful Tensorboard model graph? As you can see from the code, current session.graph isn't outputing anything helpful or comprehensible. My model is basically a chatbot model based on Seq2Seq, how do you generate more simplified and useful Tensorboard model graph?

My second question is, in NLP situation (more specifically a chatbot), what other things can you do to analyse the model in Tensorboard? And how do you enable them?

Thank you

Comment: It was originally posted https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/6288/how-do-you-use-tensorboard-to-visualise-my-chatbot-what-can-i-learn-from-it?noredirect=1#comment9332_6288 but moved to this place as it was off-topic in the other place.